# eslint complaining about 'new' or unused var, what's the proper way?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm using webpack with Vue and Highcharts. My vue file looks like this:

```
<script>
  import Highcharts from 'highcharts'

  export default{
    ready () {
      var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        ...(options)...
      })
    }
  }
</script>
```

When defined this way my linter says `'chart' is defined but never used`, but then if I take that out and just use `new Highcharts.Chart({...})` I instead get `Do not use 'new' for side effects`. What is the actual proper way to do that? Sorry if this is an obvious question, maybe I'm wording it weird but haven't had any luck googling this. I'm aware of `/*eslint-disable no-unused-vars*/` but seems like there should be a more proper way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Probably it should be a function call instead of a constructor instantiation. But that Highcharts seems a 3rd party library, which may not allow it. I would just use that `/*eslint-disable no-unused-vars*/` to make eslint shut up.

Comment: thanks @GOTO0 that does indeed fix it

Comment: @GOTO0 if you wanna post that as an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution is using the `void` operator to evaluate the new expression without adding any side effects.

```
void new Highcharts.Chart({
    ...(options)...
});
```

This will fix the ESLint validation, as long as the [`no-void`](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-void) rule is not also in use.